# Microsoft Edge does not detect gamepads

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, gamepad-api

I've been trying to test the gamepad API in Microsoft edge build 10240 using their own gamepad example http://internetexplorer.github.io/Gamepad-Sample/. This demo works in both chrome and firefox.

The `navigator.getGamepads` exists but returns an empty Array when using edge. I've tried with two different controllers, with one being a PS4 controller. Does edge only support some gamepads or do I require a more recent version of edge?

Edit: So gamepads get recognized if they're emulated as Xbox controllers. No other browser supporting the gamepad api makes distinction between different controller vendors. Are there any intent for the gamepad api in edge to support anything besides Microsoft controllers?

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this with the link you gave, my DS4 controller and Edge, seems to work flawless (except from the part where it gets recognized as Xbox) had to install DS4windows though:

http://ds4windows.com/

[image]

Edit: Recognition as Xbox is on purpose:

> By emulating a Xbox 360 controller, many more games are accessible